# How to create Boot Menu Entry in UEFI Settings using bcdedit w/o copying existing {bootmgr}

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, bcdedit

Note – This thread [How to add UEFI image boot option in BCDedit?](https://superuser.com/questions/859574/how-to-add-uefi-image-boot-option-in-bcdedit)  is similar but the answer there is irrelevant as it does not describe my case.

This thread  [How remedy situation with two EFI partitions on one drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1750357/how-remedy-situation-with-two-efi-partitions-on-one-drive)  developed my interest in this question.

I have Windows 10 and I want to create a new boot entry in UEFI setup pointing to say EFI Shell say shell.efi file residing at `\Efi\Boot\Shell\Shell.efi`.
How do I do that using bcdedit.exe without copying existing {bootmgr} windows entry?
I tried the solution provided in that answer but the command is not accepted.

```
C:\windows\system32>bcdedit /create /d "EFI_Shell" /application firmware
The application type switch specified is not valid.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
```

When I explore `/create /application` in bcdedit Help, it does not show `firmware` parameter as a valid entry.

The only `apptype` options are

```
 BOOTAPP
 BOOTSECTOR
 OSLOADER
 RESUME
 STARTUP
```

The only way I am able to do that is copying `{bootmgr}` to new entry and modifying partition, path and description in the copied entry.

But is there a direct way using bcdedit without copying `{bootmgr}` entry?

Note - There are several other ways to add a boot entry in UEFI Setup but I am specifically interested in bcdedit that too without copying `{bootmgr}` if possible.

Note - I already have working Windows 10 and BCD store already has {bootmgr} which is Windows boot manager. Like this.

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {...}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
```

The only way I am able to do right now using bcdedit command is

```
bcdedit /copy {bootmgr} /d "UEFI_Shell"
```

and then get a new GUID and update path and location etc.
However I tried the command

```
bcdedit /create /d "EFI_Shell" /application firmware
```

as already explained above and as shown in that other answer on SU, which returns invalid.
So is `bcdedit` having capability to directly create a UEFI Boot menu entry in addition to existing Windows Boot Manager, if yes, how to do that without copying existing {bootmgr} which is for Windows.

Comment: I think the article [Build a Bootable BCD from Scratch with Bcdedit](https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/build-bootable-bcd-scratch-bcdedit) has the information you need. Let me know if to put up an answer.

Comment: If I correctly understand that article talks about creating BCD from scratch. I already have {bootmgr} entry for Windows.

Comment: Unclear - you said "without copying existing {bootmgr} windows entry".

Comment: Edited the question. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Nope, it still seems to me that my link directly addresses your question.

Comment: @rajeev I don't think bcdedit provides an "official" / "orthodox" way for you to *add* an UEFI boot entry (a.k.a. firmware application) while it has an enum filter for that. It seems that it's possible to abuse a valid type like bootmgr though. (I haven't really tried, but I saw some walkthrough / guide or so online, you know.) Nevertheless, I also noticed that there's [a (third-party) PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/UEFIv2/2.6), which seems to help more "properly" / be more `efibootmgr`-like. (See its `Add-UEFIBootEntry`.)

Comment: @rajeev Also see [here](https://oofhours.com/2022/06/29/geeking-out-with-the-uefi-boot-manager/).